# Ruby Regexp using gsub is there an equivalent to self keyword?

Tags: ruby, regex, arrays, string, self

For example say I wanted to take a string and add 1 value to each a-z character. I am looking for something with a similar syntax:

```
str = 'abc123'
str.gsub(/[a-z]/, self.next!)
```

Giving an output of: bcd123
I know I could use some code like:

```
irb(main):075:0> 'abc123'.split('').map{|x| if x =~ /[a-z]/ then x.next! else x = x end }.join
=> "bcd123"
```

However, this seems to be pretty sloppy and not very efficient. I would figure there is a much neater way to accomplish the same feat.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-gsub) accepts an optional block. The return value of the block is used as a replacement string.

```
str.gsub(/[a-z]/) { |x| x.next }
# => "bcd123"
```

Shorter version using `&:next` syntax:

```
str.gsub(/[a-z]/, &:next)
# => "bcd123"
```

Comment: Answer will be accepted as soon as possible. Thanks for the insight. I can't believe how simple and elegant ruby can be. I tend to over complicate things.